# Android: Why does the gps stop 60 seconds after turning off the screen?

Tags: android, background, gps, location

I created an application that retrieves the location every second with LocationManager requestUpdateLocations.

**At first**, without using a foreground service, the location updates stopped immediately when I turned off the screen.

**Then I set up a foreground service** that implements LocationListener and GpsStatus.Listener.
I start this service with startForegroundService in my MainActivity and a notification is created in the notification bar.
(I also request the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission, which is granted, and works fine)
Now, when I turn off the screen, **I perfectly log the background locations** in onLocationChanged, **but only for 60 seconds**.
**Systematically after 60 seconds I get the event GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED** and I have no more location updates.

Because **Android announces limitations on background location retrieval**, I tried to retrieve the location every 35 seconds instead of every second. But I still get GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED after consistently 60 seconds when I expected to have at least 30 minutes of location update in the background.
On top of that, **I expected that the location updates would not occur anymore but not that the GPS would stop completely, so that it could resume 1 hour later** (Android says: "you will receive few locations per hour")

**Does anyone know why the GPS systematically shuts down after 60 seconds in the background?**
Is there a way to restart the GPS when I get the GPS_EVENT_STOPPED event ? (I tried to call locationManager.removeUpdates(myListener) and locationManager.removeGpsStatusListener(myListener) and then call requestLocationUpdates and addGpsStatusListener, but nothing to do, the GPS doesn't restart...)
is there any configuration to do to prevent the GPS from stopping ?
Do I have to "connect" my service in the background to my activity so that the gps doesn't magically stop?

Note: I always test on a real device, not on an emulator.

**This is my MyService class:**

```
class MyService: Service(), LocationListener, GpsStatus.Listener {
    private var myTime: Long? = null
    private var locationManager: LocationManager? = null

    fun startGps() {
        locationManager?.removeUpdates(this)
        locationManager?.removeGpsStatusListener(this)

        locationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

        locationManager?.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0f, this)
        locationManager?.addGpsStatusListener(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        startGps()
        super.onCreate()
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent =
            Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).let { notificationIntent ->
                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0)
            }

        val channelId = createNotificationChannel("my_service_speed", "My Speed Background Service")

        val notification: Notification = Notification.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setContentTitle("notification_title")
            .setContentText("notification_message")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_speed_icon_24)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setTicker("ticker_text")
            .build()

        // Notification ID cannot be 0.
        startForeground(111555, notification)

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel(channelId: String, channelName: String): String{
        val chan = NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE)
        chan.lightColor = Color.BLUE
        chan.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
        val service = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        service.createNotificationChannel(chan)
        return channelId
    }

    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
        if (location.hasSpeed()) {
            var tTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            if (myTime == null) {
                myTime = tTime
            } else {
                tTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            }

            var bdSpeed = BigDecimal(location.speed * 3.6)
            bdSpeed = bdSpeed.setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN)
            val speed: Double = bdSpeed.toDouble()
            println("New Speed:  ----> $speed Km/h  at second ${(tTime - myTime!!) / 1000}s")
        }
    }

    override fun onGpsStatusChanged(event: Int) {
        when (event) {
            GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS -> {
                val gs = locationManager?.getGpsStatus(null)
                var gpsSatsInFix = 0

                gs?.let {
                    val iterator: Iterator<GpsSatellite> = gs.satellites.iterator()
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        val gpssatellite = iterator.next()
                        if (gpssatellite.usedInFix()) {
                            gpsSatsInFix++
                        }
                    }
                }

                println("GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS  -->   Satellites used: $gpsSatsInFix / ${gs!!.satellites.count()} available")
            }

            GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX -> {
                println("GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX   --->   Satellites search ...")
            }
            GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED -> {
                println("GPS_EVENT_STOPPED   --->   GAME OVER ...")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And My MainActivity class:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // ... 

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // ...

        val mIntent = Intent(this, MyService::class.java)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            startForegroundService(mIntent)
        }
        
        // ...
    }
    
    // ...
    
}
```

Comment: Instead of `super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)` return `START_NOT_STICKY`

Comment: Thank you @Nitish for the comment. Unfortunately I tried this yesterday (before creating this post), but it didn't change anything... Any other ideas ?